# Microservice communication issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, netflix-eureka

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    params.put("param1", "abc");
    String fooResourceUrl = "http://pkgname1/restContoller/functionName";
    ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(fooResourceUrl, String.class, params);
   String result = restTemplate.getForObject(fooResourceUrl,String.class);
```

ERROR i am getting:
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://pkgname1/restContoller/functionName": pkgname1; nested exception is java.net.UnknownHostException: pkgname1

pkgname is spring project

Comment: The value of fooResourceUrl  is set to "http://pkgname1/restContoller/functionName" which is probably not what you want. Paste that into a browser and it will say the same thing: pkgname1 is an unknown host. Fix the address.

Comment: spring.application.name=pkgname1
i have defined them into application properties

Answer (score 1):

look at what it wrote to you: `java.net.UnknownHostException: pkgname1`
This simply means that the given host does not exist, try testing your rest controller using postman or using your browser, also read the documentation.
If you have started your microservice on a local machine, then try the following url:

`127.0.0.1:8080/replaceItWithYourContextPath`